# sp_execute_policy Error in SQL, How To Create SQL Facets Policies

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, administrator, policies

I am trying to create a policy in sql that would constrain sproc to a naming convention.

As when someone creates a new sproc they would be forced to prefix the sproc with `sp_`

Like - `sp_MySprocName`.

But I am getting the error below when i try to create a new sproc with the correct naming convention.

When I right click on Policy and choose my policy I click on the `Evaluate` option and everything runs just fine, unlike when I actually create a new sproc I get this error.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_execute_policy, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "sp_execute_policy": 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyEvaluationHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyEvaluationHelper..cctor()
System.TypeInitializationException: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyEvaluationHelper.EvaluateAutomatedPolicy(String policy, SqlXml eventData, Int64& historyId)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyEvaluationWrapper.EvaluateAutomatedPolicy(String policy, SqlXml eventData, Int64& historyId)
```

[image: Screen Shot Of Condition And Error]

What do I need to do to get ride of this error?

I have updated the stored procedures to prefix of `proc_`.   Now they're `proc_MyProcedure`.

I am still getting the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Making them prefix a stored procedure sp_ is enforcing a bad practice. If anything, you should write a policy forbidding that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem was that `microsoft.sqlserver.diadnostics.strace.dll` was not installed in the GAC. Furthermore, this file was not on my server, and not on the installation DVDs, so I couldn't install it. I found it on my PC at home, but there was a trick to getting to my work server.

I believe that I've fixed the problem by copying

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSSHell\Common7\IDE
```